# "Bring them back to society" vs "bring them back in to society"

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the two?

On Google Books "Bring them back to society" has 638 hits. And "bring them aback in to society" only has 1.

Comment: There should little difference in meaning (if any) between **to** and **into** in this sentence, but **in to** seems unlikely here: https://writingexplained.org/into-vs-in-to-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone was living away from society, (e.g. they were on an expedition in a remote area, or they were voluntarily living in seclusion for some reason), then they can be 'brought back to society' when they return to a more civilised environment.

If someone had been cast out of society, (e.g. because they had broken some rule that made them persona non grata), then they might be 'brought back into society' if their breach was later forgiven or overlooked by society.

Nonetheless, I agree with @Karolini that there is little difference in meaning between the two phrases and they can probably be used interchangeably.